# How do you suppress errors to a method call in C#?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I'm looking for an "elegant" way to suppress exceptions when calling a method.

I think the following code is way too verbose:

```
try
{ CallToMethodThatMayFail(3); }
catch {}
```

Is there some syntactic sugar I can use to say "I don't really care if this method fails"? I want to call the method and continue execution regardless of what happens with the method.

Comment: Sounds like you want nasty VB like On Error Resume Next functionality in C#!

Comment: I think that is probably as elegant as you can get.  Passing to a function to handle the error would likely be more confusing. 

I would not rely on error handling to ignore errors. I would recommend to test for your expected error cases you want to ignore and just handle it in your code.  Raising an exception is more expensive performance-wise than a conditional statement.

Comment: I'd like to point out to everybody there are niche scenarios when this is a good idea.  Like today I had to modify some code that read a dynamically created datagrid that simply creates columns based up row names from a SQL VIEW.  Occasionally the VIEW gets changed and this works fine in the code, this view may be used else where too.  For this one web page, I needed the columns named a certain way, but I don't want the code to break if somebody changes the VIEW in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is rarely a good idea to ignore/swallow errors...

To allow re-use, the only option you have is something like a method that takes an `Action`:

```
 static void IgnoreErrors(Action action) {try {action();} catch {}}
```

But you haven't exactly saved much by the time you've done:

```
SomeHelper.IgnoreErrors(() => CallToMethodThatMayFail(3));
```

I'd just leave the `try`/`catch` in place...

---

Re the question in the comment:

```
static void IgnoreErrors<T>(Action action) where T : Exception
{
    try { action(); } catch (T) {}
}

SomeHelper.IgnoreErrors<ParseException>(() => CallToMethodThatMayFail(3));
```

but I would still find it clearer to have the `try`/`catch` locally...

Comment: Is there a way that you could have an "IgnoreError" function that takes in BOTH the function to call and the errortype to ignore?
That way you wouldn't ignore system errors, but you'd be able to ignore 'parse errors' if you're iterating through tons of user entered data.

Comment: @Marc: You're right; it's rarely a good idea to do this. However, in the event that you do want to do it, what's the best way to do it? I appreciate the fact that you actually answered the questions. I'm not so appreciatiave of non-answers getting upvotes.

Comment: I might use the delegate approach if I had a lot of common handling code to run in a few scenarios... but when swallowing? I'd probably just use try { /* call method */ } catch (ExpectedException) {}

Answer (score 5):

Nope this is it.

And it's a good thing it's verbose. If you're suppressing a possible exception you better have a very good reason. The verbosity will help you or the next person who looks at the code in a few months.

Comment: With all due respect: I can make the decision about whether I have a good reason to suppress the exception. You're also assuming that this is code that someone else will actually look at.

Answer (score 4):

Using Castle, you could do something like this:

```
public class ExceptionSuppressionInterceptor : Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor
{
   public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   {
       try {
           invocation.Proceed();
       }
       catch (Exception ex) {
            // Suppressed!
       }
   }
}
```

And decorate the class you want to suppress exceptions for like this:

```
[Interceptor(typeof(ExceptionSuppressionInterceptor))]
public class GoodPracticeBreaker {

}
```

But you really probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything more terse.  I suppose you could do some AOP or similar for something more fancy.

Comment: Yeah, something AOPish is what I was thinking too. I just don't know how to actually do it.

Comment: (-1) "I don't know" doesn't really help. "Suppose you could do" isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The .Net convention is that classes implement a TryCallMayFail() method and a CallMayFail() method and the caller chooses which one to uses but the TryCallMayFail() method would include exactly what you have there.

Comment: Not not all but a few of them do and its a style I've become accustom to

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no better way to do this, and there's a good reason for it. The exception you see may mean more than "the method failed". It may mean, "the system is failing".

You probably should at least log the fact of the failure, in case it turned out to be important after all.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say this is too verbose?  If you are trying to save keystrokes, you can just use a code snippet.  If you are concerned about readability, then I think that an AOP method would be less clear to another maintainer (at least initially) and for me, this outweighs the verbosity.