# How to remove default message error on C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, usb, winpe

I'm trying to remove a message error on my C# application (WPF).It's a WinPE application.
I execute this application from a external device like a USB key. 
I would like to unplug the usb key when the application is steel open and have no error message. I just want to close the application when i remove the USB key.

Is that possible ?

Thank's very much !
Regards

Comment: You mean like this: try { } catch {}
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065943/how-do-you-suppress-errors-to-a-method-call-in-c

Comment: I already use a try catch but it steel the same memory error message.

Comment: Please make sure you have read the [ask] topics in order to get informed how to ask a good question. At least, we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution would be to use the unhandled exception event:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s, e) =>
        {
            //ignore or log the info in here
        };
    }
}
```

**However**
I would encourage you to handle this type of behaviour in your app.
- This will not make it better you will only cover the problem.
- If the application is showing error there is a reason for it and user should be aware of that.
- With this `hack` you will also lose the ability to pick on any exceptions that have happened for all the other reasons.

### - I can't say enough bad things about this approach.